# Как заменить слово оставив число? replaceALL

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

нужно в тексте поменять все LVARCHAR(n) на VARCHAR(n)
где n- любой символ
проблема в том что не знаю как оставить "n" на своём месте
чтобы LVARCHAR(5) поменялась на VARCHAR(5)
`pattern=Pattern.compile("LVARCHAR(n)").matcher("меняем LVARCHAR(21) и хочу поменять LVARCHAR(14)").replaceAll("VARCHAR(n)");`
что надо написать в регулярном выражении чтобы число осталось на месте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте обратные ссылки, возвращающие значение захватывающих подмасок (групп):

```
String s = "меняем LVARCHAR(21), LVARCHAR(1234)";
String result = s.replaceAll("\\bLVARCHAR\\((\\d+)\\)", "VARCHAR($1)");
System.out.println(result);
```

[Java-демо](http://ideone.com/tEOsph).

**Подробности**:

- `\\b` - граница слова
- `LVARCHAR\\(` - текст `LVARCHAR(`
- `(\\d+)` - (группа №1) одна или более цифр
- `\\)` - знак `)`

В шаблоне замены используется `$1`, возваращающее число, хранящееся в буфере первой (и единственной в данном выражении) захватывающей подмаски (группы).

Comment: а можно чтобы без учета регистра?

Comment: Используйте [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) или внутристрочный вариант `(?i)`: `String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\bLVARCHAR\\((\\d+)\\)", "VARCHAR($1)");`