# Найти и заменить конкретные слова в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, поиск, замена

есть текст(строка):

```
create table fsrlepj 
  (
    id serial not null ,
    objname varchar(200),
    dt datetime year to second,
    dtpod datetime year to minute not null ,
    primary key (id) 
  );
```

надо заменить `datetime year to second` и `datetime year to minute` на `TIMESTAMP(0)` без учета регистра (и большие и маленькие буквы)
и вывести все с заменой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static String replaceDates(String str){
    return str.replaceAll("(?i)(datetime year to second|datetime year to minute)", "TIMESTAMP(0)");
}
```

`(?i)` чтоб не учитывался регистр. Можно почитать про это [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: а что делает `(?i)` ?

Comment: @DiSayThis чтоб регистр не учитывался.

Comment: @DiSayThis: Я Вам об этом сегодня уже говорил (см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563730/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-replaceall#comment735250_563734)).